# computer turning on for a second and then off, looping again and again

Tags: windows

Computer turns on and all the led's light up and after a second turns back off.  It keeps on booting without me pressing the button after I first press it. If I turn it on and let it boot up and turn off, eventually it will work normally and boot up.

All I did was clean the computer from dust (which had a lot of) with my blowdryer.  I think I might have just loosened something or destroyed something.

I am not a computer scientist, nor know alot of stuff about the inside of a computer, so if you could explain it better I would appreciate it

Comment: You should've used a pressurized air can... (just sayin')

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear, a blow dryer?  The blow dryer could have wrecked something, especially if it was blowing hot air.  Also, blow dryers have blown lubricant from the electrical motor into your computer.

You may have inadvertently knocked something loose.  Your best option at this point is to take it into a computer shop where they make sure that everything is connected as it should be, like the processor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you loosened the wire connecting the on/off switch to the motherboard. Open the case and check the connectors. Usually they have a label.

[image]